# Redirect SharePoint default.aspx to new home page

Tags: sharepoint

I made a new page my home page, and going to my site using the direct path seems to work fine.  Unfortunately, my links to "Home" all target default.aspx, and how ever default.aspx reroutes them to home, it's still routing them to my old home page.  How can I update where default.aspx points?

I don't see it in the default.aspx file itself in SharePoint Designer 2013, but I am pretty clueless on this.

Answer (score 0):

How did you set your custom page as Home page?

After you created your custom home page, you can open the page and click "Make HomePage" to set it as Home page, like the below:
[image]

In my test, after I set my page as home page, if I click "Home" at the left navigation, it will redirect to the correct page.

[image]